# deploy chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to put a crx file on a server. The page is just loading, but not producing any errors.

Below is some info, if any one can help - thanks a lot.

The server is apache2 and I added to mime.types the line
application/x-chrome-extension

In the html page I have:

```
</script>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
<pre id='output'></pre>
<embed type="application/x-chrome-extension" id="complex" width='0' height='0'  
        pluginspage="complex_to_pack.crx"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

And manifest.json:

```
{
 // Required
 "name": "complex",
 "version": "1",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "plugins": [
 { "path": "npcomplex.dll", "public": true }
 ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the HTTP server configuration, it sounds like you are not setting content-type, which is most likely defaulting to `X-Content-Type-Options: no sniff`, it must be one of the following:

```
empty string
"text/plain"
"application/octet-stream"
"unknown/unknown"
"application/unknown"
"*/*"
```

Per the hosting documentation for chrome extensions (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting.html) -

`"The most common reason for failing to recognize an installable file is that the server sends the header X-Content-Type-Options: no sniff. The second most common reason is that the server sends an unknown content type—one that isn't in the previous list. To fix an HTTP header issue, either change the configuration of the server or try hosting the .crx file at another server."`